# w3c validation problem - Twitter share button pulling content

Tags: validation, twitter

I have this twitter share button that pulls 100 characters from the content of the post and its URL for the twitter share.

```
<a class="popup"
    href="http://twitter.com/share?url=<?php
        echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID));
    ?>&amp;text=<?php the_content_limit(100, "");?>">
    <img src="http://zitatezumnachdenken.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/twittersmall.png" alt="twitter">
</a>
```

It's working but I always get the following validation error
[image: Error]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending `text` unencoded. `urlencode` that just like you do the permalink.

```
<a class="popup" href="http://twitter.com/share?url=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>&amp;text=<?php echo urlencode(the_content_limit(100, ""));?>"><img src="http://zitatezumnachdenken.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/twittersmall.png" alt="twitter"></a>
```

Although, `the_content_limit` looks like it probably `echo`s (based on your usage) instead of returning a string, which you will need. So I expect you will have to find that function and alter it or duplicate it or find some other alternative to get a string that you can encode.

Comment: thanks, I'd upvote you if I had enough reputation. I used <?php $content = get_the_content();
      $content = strip_tags($content);
      echo  urlencode(substr($content, 0, 100));
?>..."> now

Comment: @onz FYI: Why use a variable that you don't need at all? You can shorten this a bit like the following: `echo urlencode(substr(strip_tags(get_the_content()), 0, 100));`.

Comment: @tf thanks, that will work even better. I don't really have a clue about PHP and I'm just googling and copying code together until it works ;)

Comment: @tf is there a way to add "..." if the string is longer than 100 characters?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your comment:

```
<?php
    $text = strip_tags(get_the_content());
    if (strlen($text) > 100)
        $text = substr($text, 0, 100).'...';
?>
<a class="popup"
    href="http://twitter.com/share?url=<?php
        echo urlencode(get_permalink());
    ?>&amp;text=<?php echo urlencode($text); ?>">
    <img src="http://zitatezumnachdenken.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/twittersmall.png"
        alt="twitter" />
</a>
```

Comment: working fine :)